# Max value from all values in column to new column

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to add new column within select statement which contains max year (stored as text) from all records and then flag it as CY/PY. Only two year are always in the table.

```
 year    value   
 2019    value1  
 2019    value2  
 2018    value3
```

So far I tried this but it returns me only max from that line, not the whole column.

```
 select year, value, IIF(year=MAX(year), 'CY', 'PY') AS "CY/PY" from table
```

expected:

```
year    value     CY/PY
2019    value1    CY
2019    value2    CY
2018    value3    PY
```

Comment: You need to get the max year from a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a window function:

```
select year, value,
       (case when year = MAX(year) over () then 'CY' else 'PY' end) AS "CY/PY"
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MAX` as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT year, value, MAX(year) OVER () AS max_year
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    year,
    value,
    IIF(year = max_year, 'CY', 'PY') AS "CY/PY"
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery in your IIF:

```
select year, value, IIF(year=(select MAX(year) from table), 'CY', 'PY') AS "CY/PY" from table
```

Comment: This actually looked good but I got error. "ERROR:  Function 'IIF(BOOL, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN)' does not exist
    Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
    You may need to add explicit typecasts" Debugging seems to be little heavy.

Comment: Try replacing the IIF with: case when year=(select MAX(year) from  table) then 'CY' else 'PY' end